# Save number in cookie and show message

Tags: html, cookies, setcookie

I need to save the age value from the input in a cookie and then alert a massage if the age is less the 18. The message should say he can't get his driver's license and if he is under 18 and to alert he can't have a driver's license.

```js
function cookiealert() {
  x = document.getElementById("agenum").value;
  if (x > 18) {
    var myText = "You can apply for drivere license"
    alert(myText)
  } else {
    var myText = "You cant apply for drivere license"
    alert(myText)
  }

}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <label>Name: </label><input type="text">
  <br>
  <label> Age:</label> <input type="number" id="agenum">
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="store in cookie and show in alert" onclick="cookiealert()">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So where do you set the cookie?

Comment: in the function and alert

Comment: So where are you setting it? Should be a line of code setting a cookie. Did you not read any tutorial on how to set a cookie?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  const d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  let expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  let name = cname + "=";
  let ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    let c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
  let user = getCookie("username");
  if (user != "") {
    alert("Welcome again " + user);
  } else {
    user = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
    if (user != "" && user != null) {
      setCookie("username", user, 365);
    }
  }
}
```

So in your code it should look like this:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue) {
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue
  }
  
  function getCookie(cname) {
    let name = cname + "=";
    let ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
      let c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
      }
      if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
      }
    }
    return "";
  }

  function cookiealert(){
    z = document.getElementById("agenum").value;
    setCookie("user", z.toString());
    x = parseInt(getCookie("user"));
    if (x > 18) {
    var myText = "You can apply for drivere license"
    alert(myText)}
    
    else {
    var myText = "You cant apply for drivere license"
    alert(myText)}
    
    }
```

You can find out more on: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: how it will be with my cod I must save it when the button is clicked

Comment: @JAM edited my answer that it contains your code, this code should work but if it doesn't please comment again.